# Why is this xpath giving a "silly node type test" warning in IntelliJ?

Tags: xslt, xpath, intellij-idea

The following xpath expression for XSLT 2.0:

```
$node/child::node()[empty(skip)]
```

...is intended to match any node() in the `$node` variable; where it is an element node with a `skip` child element, that node is ignored.

IntelliJ 2017.2.6 (and previous versions) does not like this expression and gives the following error:

```
 Silly Node type test on axis 'unknown'
```

What is IntelliJ trying to tell me? It's the first time an IDE has called my code "silly"! Normally IDEs are much more polite... And how can an xpath axis ever be unknown, and if it really is unknown, why does my stylesheet work?

Comment: Report it as two separate bugs, one for the rude language and one for the bogus message :) .

Comment: Does doing `$node/*[empty(skip)]` give the same result?

Comment: No, `$node/*[empty(skip)]` does not give the message but is not the same xpath. The first matches all nodes including text nodes, your proposed change only matches elements.

Comment: The child:: axis is redundant here, since it is the default one.

Comment: Removing it doesn't make a difference - actually I added `child::` in an attempt to get rid of the "unknown axis" part of the warning.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-202372

Comment: Source code for check: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/xpath/xpath-lang/src/org/intellij/lang/xpath/validation/XPathAnnotator.java